# Clothing Store Lesson from CodeHS

Tags: java, constructor

So I'm currently enrolled in the class with my school call Ap Computer Science in Java (Mocha). i am stuck on the stage 4.12.4. Here is the Exercise

In this problem, you’ll design a few classes that represent different pieces of clothing in a clothing store.

You’ll write the classes for TShirt, Jeans, Sweatshirt and Clothing.

The Clothing class should have two instance variables: one for the size of the clothing (a String), and another for the clothing’s color (also a string).

Clothing should have two accessor (getter methods) as well:

```
public String getSize()
public String getColor()
```

The Sweatshirt class should have a private instance variable (or field) to store whether or not it has a hood, and a corresponding getter method

```
public boolean hasHood()
```

The TShirt class should have a private field to store the fabric and a corresponding getter for that called

```
public String getFabric()
```

All Jeans should have the color blue.

The constructors should be of this format:

```
public Clothing(String size, String color)
public TShirt(String size, String color, String fabric)
public Sweatshirt(String size, String color, boolean hasHood)
public Jeans(String size)
```

Here is the Code that i have.

TShirt.java:

```
public class TShirt extends Clothing
{
private String size;
private String color;
private String fabric;


public TShirt(String Size, String Color, String Fabric)
{
    size = Size;
    color = Color;
    fabric = Fabric;
}


public String fabric()
{
    return this.fabric;
}

}
```

Jeans.java:

```
public class Jeans extends Clothing
{
private String size;
private String color = "blue";

public Jeans(String Size)
{
   size = Size;
}



public String getColor()
{
    return this.color;
}
}
```

Sweatshirt.java:

```
public class Sweatshirt extends Clothing
{
private String size;
private String color;
private boolean hasHood;

public Sweatshirt(String Size, String Color, boolean HasHood)
{
    //super(Clothing);
    size = Size;
    color = Color;
    hasHood = HasHood;

}


public boolean hasHood()
{
    return this.hasHood;
}
}
```

Clothing.java:

```
public abstract class Clothing
{
private String size;
private String color;
private String fabric;

public Clothing(String Size, String Color)
{
    this.size = size;
    this.color = color;
}

public String getSize()
{
    return this.size;
}

public String getColor()
{
    return this.color;
}

public String getFabric()
{
    return this.fabric;
}

}
```

Here is the list of Error that i got when i ran the program

```
root/TShirt.java:9: error: constructor Clothing in class Clothing cannot be applied to given types;
{
^
required: String,String
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
root/Jeans.java:7: error: constructor Clothing in class Clothing cannot be applied to given types;
{
^
required: String,String
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
root/Sweatshirt.java:8: error: constructor Clothing in class Clothing cannot be applied to given types;
{
^
required: String,String
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
3 errors
Error: Could not find or load main class ClothingTester
```

I don't know what i did wrong so please any one help me i stuck on this lesson a few days already.

Answer (score 3):

The classes that extend the Clothing class seem to be throwing the errors.  One is from TShirt (which I do not see the code for), another is from Jeans and another from Sweatshirt (which is in your posted code twice).

Whenever you extend a Class, the compiler will complain if you don’t initialize the inherited Class’s constructor right away. In all the extended classes shown, none ever do this. So to get you started I supplied a bare minimum of the Sweatshirt Class that initializes the `super` constructor or in you case it initializes `Clothing` every time you create a Sweatshirt object.  `super` is `Clothing` in this case. Also since you are extending from the Clothing class you do not need to redefine the Size and Color properties in your extended classes.

Also be careful when using different variables with the same name but are “Case” different, Example. Looking at the code you supplied, look at the Clothing class constructor. There your incoming values: Size and Color are not getting used. It should be this.size = Size and this.color = Color. Since you are using the classes own variable to set itself I am pretty sure you will get an error or simply not get the right values. I would not recommend naming different variables that only differ in Case.

```
public class Sweatshirt extends Clothing
{
   //private String size;
   //private String color;
   private boolean hasHood;

   public Sweatshirt(String inSize, String inColor, boolean inHasHood)
   {
     super(inSize, inColor);
     //super(Clothing);
     //size = Size;
     //color = Color;
     hasHood = inHasHood;  
   }

   public boolean getHasHood()
   {
     return this.hasHood;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
     return "Sweatshirt [hasHood=" + getHasHood() + ", getSize()=" + getSize() + ", getColor()=" + getColor() + "]";
   }

 }
```

Hope this helps you get started.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did :

SweatShirt

```
public class Sweatshirt extends Clothing
{

    private boolean hood;

    public Sweatshirt(String size, String color, boolean hood)
    {
        super (size,color);
        this.hood=hood;
    }

    public boolean hasHood()
    {
        return this.hood;
    }
}
```

Jeans

```
public class Jeans extends Clothing
{ 
    public Jeans(String size)
    {
       super(size,"blue");
    }
}
```

T-shirt

```
public class TShirt extends Clothing
{
    private String fabric;

    public TShirt(String size, String color, String fabric)
    {
        super(size,color);
        this.fabric=fabric;
    }

    public String getFabric()
    {
        return this.fabric;
    }
```

Clothing

```
public class Clothing
{
    // all instance variables should be private
    private String size;
    private String color;
    // private int x;

    // default constructor
    /* 
    public Clothing ()
    {
        // intialize all instance variables
        size="";
        color="";
        x=0;
    }
    */
    // only intialize when the parameter is empty or zero argument

    public Clothing(String size, String color)
    {
        this.size=size;
        this.color=color;
        // this.x=0;

        // always initialize all the instance variables
        //even though the parameters are incomplete
    }


    public String getSize()
    {
        return this.size;
    }
    public String getColor()
    {
        return this.color;
    }

}
```

You're probably done with this already, but just in case.

Comment: If you are going to answer questions, avoid giving answers that are mainly code dumps as they are not that helpful to future visitors. Instead strive to explain the reasons behind the problems that the original poster is having as well as how to solve those problems. This way your answer will be helpful to future visitors with similar problems and not just the original poster.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yup, got it. This was my first time answering so I did not keep that in mind. Sorry and thanks for pointing it out